# Backward slash added when assigning in dictionary. how to avoid it

Tags: python, encode

When i assign a windows path as a value in dictionary, the backward slash gets added.

I did try using raw string.

```py
p = "c:\windows\pat.exe"
print p
c:\windows\pat.exe
d = {"p": p}
print d
{'p': 'c:\\windows\\pat.exe'}

Tried it as raw string
d = {"p": r"%s" % p}
print d
{'p': 'c:\\windows\\pat.exe'}
```

I dont want the backslash to added when assigned to value in dictionary.

Comment: There isn't actually 2 backslashes in that string, its just represented that way due to escape sequences. Try `print d['p']` as proof.

Answer (score 4):

This is a mistake that's very common among people new to Python.

TL;DR:

```
>>> print "c:\windows\pat.exe" == 'c:\\windows\\pat.exe'
True
```

Explanation:

In the first instance, where you're assigning a value to the string `p` and then printing `p`, Python gets the string to print itself and it does so by outputting its literal value. In your example:

```
>>> p = "c:\windows\pat.exe"
>>> print p
c:\windows\pat.exe
```

In Python 3, the same:

```
>>> p = "c:\windows\pat.exe"
>>> print(p)
c:\windows\pat.exe
```

In the second instance, since you're creating and then printing a dictionary, Python asks the dictionary to print itself. It does so by printing a short Python code representation of itself, since there is no standard simple way of printing a dictionary, like there is for variables with simple types like strings or numbers.

In your example (slightly modified to work by itself):

```
>>> d = {"p": "c:\windows\pat.exe"}
>>> print d
{'p': 'c:\\windows\\pat.exe'}
```

So, why does the value of `p` in the Python code representation have the double backslashes? Because a single backslash in a string literal has an ambiguous meaning. In your example, it just so happens that `\w` and `\p` don't have special meanings in Python. However, you've maybe seen things like `\n` and perhaps `\t` used in strings to represent a new line or a tab character.

For example:

```
>>> print "Hello\nworld!"
Hello
world!
```

So how does Python know when to print a new line and when to print `\n` literally, when you want to? It doesn't. It just assumes that if the character after the `\` doesn't make for a special character, you probably wanted to write a `\` and if it is, you wanted to write the special character. If you want to literally write a `\`, regardless of what follows, you need to follow up the escape character (that's what the `\` is called in this context) with another one.

For example:

```
>>> print "I can see \\n"
I can see \n
```

That way, there is no ambiguity and Python knows exactly what is intended. You should always write backslashes as double backslashes in normal string literals, instead of relying on luck in avoiding control characters like `\n` or `\t`. And that's why Python, when printing its code version of your string `"c:\windows\pat.exe"`, prefers to write it as `'c:\\windows\\pat.exe'`. Using single quotes, which are preferred even though double quotes are fine too and using double backslashes.

It's just how it is written in code, "really" your string has single backslashes and the quotes are of course not part of it at all.

If you don't like having to write double backslashes, you can consider using 'raw strings', which is prefixing a string with `r` or `R`, telling Python to ignore special characters and take the string exactly as written in code:

```
>>> print r"This won't have \n a line break"
This won't have \n a line break
```

But watch out! This doesn't work if you want your last characters in the string to be an odd number of `\`, for reasons not worth getting into. In that case, you have no other recourse than writing the string with double backslashes:

```
>>> print r"Too bad\"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print r"Too bad\"
                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> print r"Too bad\\"
Too bad\\
>>> print "Too bad\\"
Too bad\
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not a problem, because when you print the values (not the whole dictionary) the string will have one backslash

```
p = "c:\windows\pat.exe"
d = {"p": p}
print (d)
{'p': 'c:\\windows\\pat.exe'}

for i in d:
    print("key:", i, " value:", d[i])
```

Output

```
{'p': 'c:\\windows\\pat.exe'}
key: p  value: c:\windows\pat.exe
>>>
```